# error Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: 404

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-grid, appium-android

I want to connect selenium grid with nodes in appium. In the first place, I created two devices to emulate in android studio and I make their JSON code:

```
"capabilities": [
    {
          "browserName": "Chrome",
          "deviceName": "Android Emulator",
          "platformName": "Android",
          "maxInstances": "1",
          "udid": "emulator-5558"
    }
],
"configuration": {
    "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
    "timeout": 30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:4730/wd/hub",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "port": "4730",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "hubPort": "4444"

}
```

In the second place I run the selenium grid with this code:

```
 java –jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar and this run 
satisfactorily.
```

Finally I run the nodes appium with this code:

```
appium --address 127.0.0.1  --nodeconfig node1.json -p 4730 -cp 4730
```

But this show this error:

> Request to register with grid was unsuccessful: 404 - "\n\n\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n    var json = Object.freeze('{\"consoleLink\": \"\u002fwd\u002fhub\",\"type\": \"Standalone\",\"class\": \"org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpHandler$DisplayHelpServletConfig\",\"version\": \"3.141.59\"}');\n  \n\n\n\n\n  \n
>
> \n
>
> ### Selenium  v.
>
> \n  \n\n  \n
>
> \n      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.\n
>
> \n
>
> \n      For more information about Selenium  please see the\n      docs and/or visit the wiki.\n      \n        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium  console.\n      \n
>
> \n
>
> \n      Happy Testing!\n
>
> \n  \n\n  \n    \n      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from\n      these https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS\">people, and our\n      http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/\">sponsors.\n   \n  \n \n\n\n"

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Try `appium --address 127.0.0.1  -role node -nodeConfig node1.json -p 4730 -cp 4730`

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The pattern:

```
.... -role node (options)...
```

You miss `-role node` to execute the options, try:

```
appium --address 127.0.0.1 -role node -nodeConfig node1.json -p 4730 -cp 4730
```

See docs for detail:

[Node Configuration](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#node-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same issue while I was following a tutorial video in setting up the Appium node. Have spent a solid 3 hours trying to find out what went wrong with my JSON file until I found this [Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/toml_options/#relaying-commands-to-a-service-endpoint-that-supports-webdriver).

For those who are using Selenium 4, apparently we no longer have to setup the config file on Appium's side anymore, simply uses the config with Selenium 4.

```
 java -jar selenium-server-4.14.0.jar node --port 6666 --hub http://<hub-ip>:4444 --config /path/to/file/<file-name>.toml
```

The port is optional, if you do not have any nodes that's using the port 5555 by default, you can just omit it.

I know this problem has already been solved, but I'm just trying to provide the latest solution here so newbies like me can save their time in setting up a node. :D